# How do I separate 2 groups with a regex?

Tags: regex, match, grouping

First time asking a question.
So, I'm learning regex and I got this exercise:

input string:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Retreat the following two groups using a regex to get the following:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
```

and

```
Communications link failure
```

avoiding the colon `:` after CommunicationsException.

**My solution is:**

```
Caused\s+by:\s+[A-Za-z.]+\d[.]+[A-Za-z]+|\s+...+
```

It worked, but I'm sure its really messy.
Could anybody explain to me how to upgrade it?

Comment: There is no grouping in your regex though? `(Caused by:.*?):\s*(.*)` is the simplest way, if your dialect supports `.*?` (non-greedy quantifiers). That said, per rules of the [tag:regex] tag, you should additionally tag with dialect/engine/programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match `Cause by:` and then match all text up to the next colon, and then start matching from any non-whitespace that is not a colon till the end of string:

```
Caused\s+by:[^:]+|[^:\s].*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/191g0g/1). If the match is at the start of the string, add `^` at the start.

As an alternative, if you do not care what text is at the string beginning, you can even use `^[^:]+:[^:]+|[^:\s].*`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `Caused\s+by:` - `Caused by:` with any one or more whitespaces between `Caused` and `by`
- `[^:]+` - one or more chars other than `:`
- `|` - or
- `[^:\s]` - a char other than whitespace and `:`
- `.*` - the rest of the line.